# TextArea Data Sanitizing Before Storing In MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

Here's the problem scenario.  I have a textbox in which users can input comments.  However, if they include HTML tags or `<A HREF='javascript:window.alert("Example of a link that displays an alert box");'> link </A>`, and when the comments are outputted onto the page from the MySQL database, they actually execute.  I'm looking for a way to prevent that from happen and only allow a few HTML tags to be used (like bold, italics, underline).

I'm using this function on my comments before sending the comments from the textarea to be stored on the mysql database:

```
function sanitize($data)
{
// remove whitespaces (not a must though)
$data = trim($data); 

// apply stripslashes if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
$data = stripslashes($data);
}

// a mySQL connection is required before using this function
$data = mysql_real_escape_string($data);

return $data;
}
```

Comment: How should unsupported tags be processed? Display as-is or get removed?

Comment: display as is so as not to take anything away from the comment

Comment: the concept of this function is all wrong. trim has nothing to do with sanitization, - magic quotes has nothing to do with database and the only thing you really need is mysql_real_escape_string(), so, you can use this function alone.

Comment: okay, but any idea on the way to handle the problem of HTML tags and javascript?

Comment: yes, I have, but you have already accepted the answer which doesn't answer your question at all. good luck with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there was no answer how to allow certain tags to remain intact.

strip_tags() function, which comes first to one's mind, is not safe at all, it will allow dangerous JS attributes.

So, you have to use some utility like HTML Purifier, or some regexp that will allow only certain tags and eliminate all others or for for BBCode.

Comment: after some digging, I found htmlawed > http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php It is incredible. Easy and meets my requirements.